# What are the various auto launch paths mean in OSX?

Tags: macos, mojave, launchd, startup, daemons

I'm trying to track down sneaky apps that launch upon reboot. They are not in `System Preferences > Users and Groups > Login items` and the in-app preferences for auto starting is disabled too for them. I did find them here:

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents
/Library/LaunchAgents
/Library/LaunchDaemons
/System/Library/LaunchAgents
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons
```

What do each folder mean? Does removing the file from here simply mean the OS is won't find it on startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in the [`launchd` man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/launchctl/):

> ```
> ~/Library/LaunchAgents          Per-user agents provided by the user.
>  /Library/LaunchAgents          Per-user agents provided by the administrator.
>  /Library/LaunchDaemons         System-wide daemons provided by the administrator.
>  /System/Library/LaunchAgents   Per-user agents provided by Apple.
>  /System/Library/LaunchDaemons  System-wide daemons provided by Apple.
> ```

If you want to remove something from starting, *unload* it using the `launchctl` utility:

```
$ [sudo] launchctl unload foo.bar.plist
```

If there's a "sneeky app" that persists across reboot, it would most likely be in the first three; the last two are "Apple only."

Answer (score 0):

The items in the **/LaunchAgents** and **/LaunchDaemon** folders are [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW1-SW1) property list files that configure those background tasks.  Files in the local and user Library folders would be for items that have been installed for all users or a particular user, respectively, while those in the System folder are, well, part of the system, and really shouldn’t be messed with.  Usually you would use [launchctl](https://ss64.com/osx/launchctl.html) to load or unload daemons and agents.